# Flutter add ScrollView and Background image

Tags: flutter, scrollview, background-image

Hello i am trying to put a ScollView to my app but the problem is that i can't have both ScrollView and Background image so if someone can help me with that (here i put the background image so how can i put the scrollview now ?) I had the 2 working but not both in the same time, the scrollview i used was the singleChildScrollView

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
  home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _State createState() => _State();

}

AudioCache cache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: new AudioPlayer());

void PlayBest() {

  cache.play('best.mp3');

}

void StopBest() {

 cache.play('pro.mp3');

}
MediaQueryData queryData;



double lecran = queryData.size.width;
double loecran = queryData.size.height;
double ratio = queryData.textScaleFactor;



class MyImagePro extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var assetsImage = new AssetImage('assets/iconhd.png');
var image = new Image(image: assetsImage, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.5, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.5,);
  return new Container(child: image,);
}}

class MyImagePro2 extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var assetsImage = new AssetImage('assets/trumpfond.png');
var image = new Image(image: assetsImage, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.longestSide,);
  return new Container(child: image,);
}}


class _State extends State<MyApp> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

        body: new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("assets/trumpfond.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            child: new Column( 
            children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),

                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: PlayBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: StopBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/9)),    // LEFT // TOP // RIGHT // BOTTOM //
                  new Text("Song 1"),
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.2)),
                  new Text("Song 2"),
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: PlayBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: StopBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/9)),    // LEFT // TOP // RIGHT // BOTTOM //
                  new Text("Song 3"),
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.2)),
                  new Text("Song 4"),
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
              new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: PlayBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
              new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
              new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: StopBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                ],
              ),
              new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0)),    // LEFT // TOP // RIGHT // BOTTOM //
                  new Text("Song 1"),
                  new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(140.0, 10.0, 20.0, 0.0)),
                  new Text("Song 2"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
            ),);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried a Stack?

Comment: Yes it worked .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can achieve using [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

i hope that following may help you.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage("images/p2.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),

                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: PlayBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                      new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: StopBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/9)),    // LEFT // TOP // RIGHT // BOTTOM //
                      new Text("Song 1"),
                      new Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4.2)),
                      new Text("Song 2"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: PlayBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                      new Expanded(child: new FlatButton(onPressed: StopBest, child: new MyImagePro(),),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked perfectly

Comment: can you please add another question with some code.

Comment: Do you also know a way for to implement something similar like just replacing the image with a vertical PageView and still be able to use both vertical PageView and my SingleChildScrollView ?

Comment: please add some image or code to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: Using this way, the background remains at fixed position. I want it to be scrolled as well. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can we stretch the image to  bottom?
for eg. if scroll view height is 500 then background image height should be 500, and if scroll view height is 1000 then when user scrolls image should be scrollable?