# Flutter. Whitespace on screen

Tags: android, dart, flutter

[image]

My code is

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final logo = Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png", fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
final emailField = TextField(
  obscureText: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
      labelText: "Email",
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      border:
      OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide(),
      )
  ),
);
final passwordField = TextField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
      labelText: "Password",
      border:
      OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        borderSide: BorderSide()
      )
  ),
);
final loginButton = Material(
  elevation: 5.0,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13.0),
  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 97, 143),
  child: MaterialButton(
    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("Login",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
        )
    ),
  ),
);

final background = BoxDecoration(
  image: DecorationImage(
    image: ExactAssetImage("assets/images/background .png"),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop)
  ),
);

return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      decoration: background,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 85.0,),
          logo,
          SizedBox(height: 130.0,),
          emailField,
          SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
          passwordField,
          SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
          loginButton
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
);
}
```

I don't know how to remove the whitespace, can anyone explain me what's wrong with my code?

I added *SingleChildScrollView* 'cause keyboard hides textfield if I don't use it but without *SingleChildScrollView* I don't get the whitespace.

Removing *SingleChildScrollView* could work but I have the problem with keyboard.

Maybe another way to do it.

I'm stuck on it.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe have a look at [this answer that uses a stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52680688/4465386) .

Comment: @Zvi Karp that works!! Thank you!! Do you know why happened that??

Comment: A `SingleChildScrollView` has a infinite height, therefor flutter can't make the image to cover the whole `SingleChildScrollView` even that you set `fit: BoxFit.cover`.

Comment: @Zvi Karp Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have several problems with those SizedBox you are using as separators. But you can remove that white space adding some height to your main Container.
something like this:

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // add this line
        decoration: background,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
```

Comment: Thank you, solved my problem too! (Zvi Karp's answer works as well). What problems can I have with SizedBox?? And what can be a better way??

Comment: if you declare the containers height, there is no point in warping it in a scrollable. If the form is long and requires the user to scroll - then if you use a stack, the image would stay static it the background and the form would scroll, but if you declare the containers height, you won't be able to scroll.